# My .bat file won't give a proper output and it stops after reading the first input

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've tried a few things but I can't seem to get my .bat file to give proper output and read past the first line of the input. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am trying to create this for mass account creation in Active Directory.

```
@echo off
echo ---- >C:\NewUserCreation\createdusers.txt

setlocal
FOR /F "eol=; tokens=1-12* delims=~" %%i in (C:\NewUserCreation\newusers.txt) do (

set "_lastname=%%i"
set "_firsname=%%j"
set _QWERTY=%%k
call set _midinit=%%_QWERTY:~0,2%%
set _edipi=%%l
set _ptc=%%m
set _ranktitle=%%n
set _subcomponent=%%o
set _unit=%%p
set _position=%%q
set _email=%%r
set _descr=%%s

call :do_user
)
endlocal
notepad C:\NewUserCreation\createdusers.txt
goto :EOF


:do_user
if "%_midinit%"=="%_edipi%" goto :no_middlename
set _samacctname1=%_firsname%.%_midinit%.%_lastname%
set _userPrincipalName=%_edipi%
call :find_existing_user
call set _samacctname=%_samaccountname%
call set _lastinit=%%_lastname:~0,1%%



C:\NewUserCreation\admod -h mydomaincontroller -add -b "cn=%_lastname%\, %_firsname% %_midinit%,ou=NewUsers,ou=n,ou=n,dc=n,dc=n,dc=n,dc=n" objectclass::user "sn::%_lastname%" "givenname::%_firsname%" "initials::%_midinit%" "personaltitle::%_ranktitle%" "company::%_subcomponent%" "department::%_unit%" "PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName::%_position%" "title::%_position%" "employeetype::%_ptc%" "displayname::%_descr%" "description::%_descr%" "samaccountname::%_samacctname%" "st::Anywhere,US" "streetAddress::%_unit%" "postalCode::36805" "countryCode::111" "c::USA" "co::United States" "l::Corporation" "telephoneNumber::DSN 318-872-XXXX" "userPrincipalName::%_edipi%@domain" "userPassword::password"

if /I %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
set _resultcode=Success
if /I %_samnametest% EQU 274 (call set _resultcode=%%_resultcode%%-DUP)
) ELSE set _resultcode=-ERROR-

@echo on

sleep 15

net user %_samacctname% /DOMAIN /passwordreq:yes


C:\Windows\System32\dsquery * "ou=n,ou=n,dc=n,dc=n,dc=n,dc=n" -filter "(&(objectclass=user)(samaccountname=%_samacctname%))" -s mydomain |exchmbx -me SMTP:%_email%"

@echo off

echo %_resultcode%. . .     %_samacctname%      Contact: SMTP:%_email% >>C:\NewUserCreation\createdusers.txt
goto :EOF




:find_existing_userz
set _search4Name=%_samacctnamez%
call set _samNameSearchz=%%_search4Name:~0,20%%
call set _samNameSearchzv=%%_search4Name:~0,16%%274

C:\Windows\System32\dsquery * "ou=n,ou=n,dc=n,dc=n,dc=n,dc=n" -filter "(&(&(samaccountname=%_search4Name%)(ObjectClass=User))(!objectClass=computer))" -attr samaccountname|find /I "%_samNameSearchz%" >"%_samNameSearchz%.tmp"

call :samnamefilesizez %_samNameSearchz%.tmp _samNameSearchsizez
del %_samNameSearchz%.tmp
if /I %_samNameSearchsizez% LEQ 1 (set _samaccountnamez=%_samNameSearchz%) ELSE (
set _samaccountnamez=%_samNameSearchzv%
set _lastnamez=%_lastnamez%274
)
echo resulting_sam_account_name %_samaccountnamez%
call set _samnametestz=%_samaccountnamez:~-3%
goto :EOF



:find_existing_user
set _search4Name=%_samacctname1%
call set _samNameSearch=%%_search4Name:~0,20%%
call set _samNameSearchv=%%_search4Name:~0,16%%274

C:\Windows\System32\dsquery * "ou=n,ou=n,dc=n,dc=n,dc=n,dc=n" -filter "(&(&(samaccountname=%_samNameSearch%)(ObjectClass=User))(!objectClass=computer))" -attr samaccountname|find /I "%_samNameSearch%" >%_samNameSearch%.tmp

call :samnamefilesize %_samNameSearch%.tmp _samNameSearchsize
del %_samNameSearch%.tmp
if /I %_samNameSearchsize% LEQ 1 (set _samaccountname=%_samNameSearch%) ELSE (
set _samaccountname=%_samNameSearchv%
set _lastname=%_lastname%274
)
echo resulting_sam_account_name %_samaccountname%
call set _samnametest=%_samaccountname:~-3%
goto :EOF

:samnamefilesize
set %2=%~z1
goto :EOF

:samnamefilesizez
set %2=%~z1
goto :EOF




pause
```

Comment: Since you're dealing with `for` loops and env vars you should read about [delayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). Also, the code seems too long (not easy to follow).

Comment: Try work with a smaller amount of code if you are new to batch. What kind of accounts are you trying to make?

Comment: Please read this help topic: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)! And please read at least the [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how this site works!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you are **call**ing :do_user, and that is **go**ing **to** :no_middlename. I can only guess that there is nothing at :no_middlename returning it to the call within your original for loop.